# How to manage VersionOne member groups via the API?

Tags: rest, versionone

I'd like to add and remove members from a specific member group via the VersionOne APIs. I've looked through the documentation and the meta.v1 information and haven't been able to find anything related to member groups. How can I add or remove members from a member group using the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal system name for a Member Group is **MemberLabel**.

A MemberLabel asset has a multi-relation attribute called Members that you can use to add or remove members.

This meta query shows you the attributes of the MemberLabel asset:

```
http://localhost/versionone/meta.v1/MemberLabel?xsl=api.xsl
```

To add a member to a MemberLabel, issue a HTTP POST with a XML payload similar to the following:

```
<Asset>
    <Relation name="Members">
        <Asset idref="Member:20" act="add"/>
    </Relation>
</Asset>
```